# Change attribute inside foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm using laravel, and I have a table with id, category_name, parent_id, desc, and url.

Then in the view, I foreach the table with this code:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $category->parent_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $category->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $category->url }}</td>
        <td class="center">
            <a href="{{ url('/admin/edit-category/'.$category->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">Edit</a> 
            <a href="{{ url('/admin/delete-category/'.$category->id) }}" class="delCat btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a>
        </td>            
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

now, instead of showing parent_id, I want to show the parent category name. 
I've tried a lot of things but nothing work.

I know this might be a very easy question, but I'm just started learning web development by myself. So please bear with me.

Thank you.

Comment: In place where you pass this data to view you need to fetch that Category first and then pass it's name. For example `Category::find($category->parent_id)->name`

Comment: @Dexa it's a better practice not to instantiate a new model inside of a view and use/eager load a relationship instead before passing the data to the view.

Comment: @Devon True, but for a start let's just get the category name in controller, and then he can move relationship to model. From the question this sounds like easier for OP to grasp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Define the parent relationship in the Category model.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships
2. Eager load that relationship in the query where you are fetching the categories.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
3. Access the loaded relationship in the view, eg. `$category->parent->name`